# Chaining Drop-Down Lists

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm doing my first project in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I'm fluent in Java and C.

[image]

I have a group of images that are separated in multi level groups/subgroups. Before I present them I need to choose the groups using DDL (Drop-Down Lists). I want to display the first DDL and only after selected, present the 2nd and so on. For example I have a DDL with [Group A, Group B, Group C] and if I choose Group A then it appears a 2nd DDL with the options [Group AA, Group AB]. If I choose the Group AA then it appears a 3rd DDL. If I choose the Group AB the pictures from that group should be presented (because there are no subgroups inside Group AB). I only need at most 3 levels (like in the picture). The groups are fixed, they never change.

Keep in mind that if I'm in Group AAA and I change the first DDL to Group B, the 2nd DDL should reset (and change its options) and the 3rd DDL should disappear.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle to demo this. Hopefully it is what you are trying to accomplish. The fiddle is very basic and could be refined and refactored to be more dynamic/generic

```js
var optionAppendValues = ["A", "B", "C"];

function createTwo() {
    var selectOneValue = document.getElementById('images_one').value;
  var selectTwo = document.getElementById('images_two');
        resetTwo();
      resetThree();
      if(selectOneValue !== "default") {
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Group " + selectOneValue + optionAppendValues[i];
      option.value = selectOneValue + optionAppendValues[i];
      selectTwo.add(option);
    }
    selectTwo.style.display = "block"; 
      }
}

function createThree() {
        var selectTwoValue = document.getElementById('images_two').value;
    var selectThree = document.getElementById('images_three');
    resetThree();   
    if(selectTwoValue !== "default") {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = "Group " + selectTwoValue + optionAppendValues[i];
      option.value = selectTwoValue + optionAppendValues[i];
      selectThree.add(option);
    }
    selectThree.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function resetTwo(){
  var selectTwo = document.getElementById('images_two');
    for (i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      selectTwo.remove(i);
    }  
    selectTwo.style.display = "none";
}

function resetThree(){
  var selectThree = document.getElementById('images_three');
    for (i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      selectThree.remove(i);
    }  
    selectThree.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#images_two, #images_three {
  display:none;
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="images_one">Images:</label>

  <select name="images_one" id="images_one" onchange="createTwo()">
    <option value="default">Please select...</option>
    <option value="A">Group A</option>
    <option value="B">Group B</option>
    <option value="C">Group C</option>
  </select>
  
   <select name="images_two" id="images_two" onchange="createThree()">
       <option value="default">Please select...</option>
  </select>
  
     <select name="images_three" id="images_three">
         <option value="default">Please select...</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!